# Parametrization Of A Curve - Intersection $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ And $x+y=1$

Tags: calculus, parametrization

> Find parametrization of the curve given by the intersection of the unit sphere  $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ and $x+y=1$

So look on the intersection:

$$x^2+(1-x)^2+z^2=1\iff 2x^2-2x+z^2=0\iff 4(x-\frac{1}{2})^2+2z^2=1$$

Plug in just $x=\cos t,y=\sin t$ would not be useful?

we need to chose functions of $\cos t$ and $\sin t$ that will be based on $\cos^2x+\sin^2x=1$? or $x=\frac{1}{2}\cos t+\frac{1}{2}$ and $z=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \sin t$?

Comment: The last parameterization you list would work nicely, though in that case $y$ should be $z$. You can verify it works by substituting $x(t),y(t)=1-x(t),z(t)$ into $x^2+y^2+z^2$ and see it reduces to $1$.

Comment: As user170231 says, the parameterization you've chosen is good, but you've assigned $\ \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \sin t\ $ to the wrong variable (possibly just a typo?), and you also need to include all three variables, so your full parameterization should be $\ x= \frac{1}{2}\cos t+ \frac{1}{2}\ $,$\ y= \frac{1}{2}- \frac{1}{2}\cos t\ $, $\ z= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \sin t\ $.

Comment: The equation that you have in the first line doesn’t represent the intersection. It is the equation of a cylinder that contains the intersection.

Answer (score 1):

This yields the same result but gives insight on the intersection shape.

Define $u=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(x+y)$ and $v=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(x-y)$. We get $u^{2}+v^{2}+z^{2}=1$, $u=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$, and consequently $v^{2}+z^{2}=\frac{1}{2}$.

This is a circle on the $yz$ plane, centered on origin with radius $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$, translated $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\hat{i}$ and rotated $\frac{\pi}{4}\hat{k}$.

The parametrization is $u=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$, $v=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\cos{t}$, $z=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\sin{t}$ or $x=\frac{1}{2}(1+\cos{t})$, $y=\frac{1}{2}(1-\cos{t})$, $z=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\sin{t}$